# Subquery returns more than 1 row - Multiple selects MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

My query is

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT invoice_custom_fieldvalue FROM ip_invoice_custom WHERE invoice_id ='2474' AND invoice_custom_fieldid = '9'
) AS 'Claim Number',
(
    SELECT invoice_custom_fieldvalue FROM ip_invoice_custom WHERE invoice_id ='2474' AND invoice_custom_fieldid = '7'
) AS 'Client Name',
(
    SELECT invoice_custom_fieldvalue FROM ip_invoice_custom WHERE invoice_id ='2474' AND invoice_custom_fieldid = '8'
) AS 'Employer',
(
    SELECT invoice_item_subtotal FROM ip_invoice_amounts WHERE invoice_amount_id ='2474'
) AS 'Invoice Amount',
(
    SELECT invoice_item_tax_total FROM ip_invoice_amounts WHERE invoice_amount_id ='2474'
) AS 'Tax',
(
    SELECT invoice_item_subtotal FROM ip_invoice_amounts WHERE invoice_amount_id ='2474'
) AS 'Tax1',
(
    SELECT CONCAT('CAD') FROM ip_invoice_amounts WHERE invoice_amount_id ='2474'
) AS 'Currency',
(
    SELECT invoice_date_created FROM ip_invoices WHERE invoice_id ='2474'
) AS 'Date',
(
    SELECT client_name FROM ip_clients c INNER JOIN ip_invoices i ON c.client_id = i.client_id WHERE i.invoice_id ='2474'
) AS 'Requested by',
(
    SELECT item_description FROM ip_invoice_items p WHERE p.invoice_id
) AS 'Transaction Subtype';
```

This is the result without the last select:

```
Claim Number    Client Name Employer    Invoice Amount  Tax  Tax1   Currency    Date    Requested by
12345           John Smith  NULL        3326.99         0.00 0.00   CAD 2019-12-04  ATTN: Joe Smith
```

ip_invoice_items table looks like:

```
item_id invoice_id item_description
1       2474       Some product
2       2474       Some other product
3       2474       Some other other product
```

Desired output:

```
Claim Number    Client Name Employer    Invoice Amount  Tax  Tax1   Currency    Date    Requested by Item Description
12345           John Smith  NULL        3326.99         0.00 0.00   CAD 2019-12-04  ATTN: Joe Smith  Some product
12345           John Smith  NULL        3326.99         0.00 0.00   CAD 2019-12-04  ATTN: Joe Smith  Some other product
12345           John Smith  NULL        3326.99         0.00 0.00   CAD 2019-12-04  ATTN: Joe Smith  Some other other product
```

There are multiple item descriptions for each invoice_id (Last select statement). How can I rewrite this so I am getting a result that will add rows for each item description?

Comment: could you show sample schema (output of `show create table tablename` for all your tables), sample data, the results you are getting, and the results you want to get?

Comment: Thanks @ysth I've updated the question with schema information.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @forpas - Updated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 5 tables involved and you can start with `ip_invoice_custom` and `LEFT` join the other 4:

```
SELECT ic.`Claim Number`, ic.`Client Name`, ic.`Employer`,
       ia.invoice_item_subtotal `Invoice Amount`,
       ia.invoice_item_tax_total `Tax`,
       ia.invoice_item_subtotal `Tax1`,
       'CAD' `Currency`,
       i.invoice_date_created `Date`,
       c.client_name `Requested by`,
       ii.item_description `Transaction Subtype`
FROM (
  SELECT invoice_id, 
         MAX(CASE WHEN invoice_custom_fieldid = '9' THEN invoice_custom_fieldvalue END) `Claim Number`,
         MAX(CASE WHEN invoice_custom_fieldid = '7' THEN invoice_custom_fieldvalue END) `Client Name`,
         MAX(CASE WHEN invoice_custom_fieldid = '8' THEN invoice_custom_fieldvalue END) `Employer`
  FROM ip_invoice_custom
  WHERE invoice_id ='2474' AND invoice_custom_fieldid IN ('7', '8', '9')
  GROUP BY invoice_id
) ic
LEFT JOIN ip_invoice_amounts ia ON ia.invoice_amount_id = ic.invoice_id 
LEFT JOIN ip_invoices i ON i.invoice_id = ic.invoice_id 
LEFT JOIN ip_clients c ON c.client_id = i.client_id
LEFT JOIN ip_invoice_items ii ON ii.invoice_id = ic.invoice_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this all with one select statement by joining the tables on the invoice id. For the custom table, you can join that table 3 times to get the value for each custom value.

Here is a rough sketch of what that would look like:

```
SELECT cn1.invoice_custom_fieldvalue as 'Claim Number', 
    cn2.invoice_custom_fieldvalue as 'Client Name',
    em.invoice_custom_fieldvalue as 'Employer',
    ip_invoice_amounts.invoice_item_subtotal as 'Invoice Amount',
    ip_invoice_amounts.invoice_item_tax_total as 'Tax',
    CONCAT('CAD') as 'Currency',
    ip_clients.client_name as 'Requested by',
    ip_invoice_items.item_description as 'Transaction Subtype'
FROM ip_invoice_custom cn1
    JOIN ip_invoice_custom cn2 
       ON cn1.invoice_id=cn2.invoice_id
    JOIN ip_voice_custom em
       ON cn1.invoice_id=em.invoice_id 
    JOIN ip_invoice_amounts 
       ON cn1.invoice_id=invoice_amounts.invoice_amount_id
    JOIN ip_invoices
       ON cn1.invoice_id=ip_invoices.invoice_id
    JOIN ip_clients
       ON ip_invoices.client_id=ip_clients.client_id
    JOIN ip_invoice_items
       ON cn1.invoice_id=ip_invoice_items.invoice_id
WHERE cn1.invoice_custom_fieldid = '9' 
    AND cn2.invoice_custom_fieldid = '7'
    AND em.invoice_custom_fieldid = '8'
    AND cn1.invoice_id = '2474';
```

I am not sure what you are doing for the currency line so that might need to be edited but this does the entire search in one select statement.

Working with your original code you could also join your select statement with the ip_invoice_items table. You could join the larger select statement, not including the last sub select, with the ip_invoice_table where the ip_invoice_id equals the value you are looking for. Here is a rough sketch of what you could do:

```
SELECT Claim_Number, Client_Name_Employer, Invoice_Amount, Tax,
   Tax1_Currency, Date, item_description
FROM ip_invoice_items JOIN 
   ( ... ) as ip_info  
WHERE ip_invoice_items.item_id = '2474';
```

In the parenthesis you can include the larger select statement. I also recommend giving the sub_select statements non-string names and beautifying the output in the outer select statement.

Comment: Thanks @vasco Madrid. The problem I have is the poor relational structure of the database. In the first three select statements, I am trying to get values based on two criteria in the same table. In ip_invoice custom the table has multiple rows with the invoice ID '2474' and based on the custom_field_id in that table it will display Claim number, client name or employer. How can I structure the query without multiple selects to accomplish getting that data with multiple criteria?

Comment: @mcook16 can you add to your question what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: Updated. Thanks!

Comment: @mcook16 maybe I misunderstand this question, but are you asking how you can combine the select statements from your original question into one select statement? The answer I suggested should give you the desired output if you include your original code in the parenthesis.

Comment: my problem is the first three selects are dependent on two WHERE clauses in the same table (invoice_custom_fieldid = '9', '7', etc. I am unsure of how to get this data using the code you provided.

Comment: I just updated my answer so that the entire query is done in one select statement. In my first recommendation you leave the query exactly how you have it in the question but paste it into the parenthesis and edit the column titles. But this query would have 3 nested select statements, so I recommend the second one if you would like one select statement.